# Laravel 5.2 - Modelizer/Laravel-Selenium - WARN - Exception thrown java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException

Tags: java, php, laravel, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a EC2 instance with ubuntu 14.04, Apache2, php 7.2, Laravel 5.2.

I install:
composer require modelizer/selenium "~1.0",
java,
,sudo apt-get install chromium-chromedriver

**This is my test SeleniumExampleTest.php:**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithoutMiddleware;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseTransactions;
use Modelizer\Selenium\SeleniumTestCase;

class SeleniumExampleTest extends SeleniumTestCase
{
    /**
     * A basic functional test example.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function testBasicExample()
    {
        // This is a sample code you can change as per your current scenario
        $this->visit('/')
             ->see('Laravel')
             ->hold(3);
    }
}
```

**This is how i run it:**

One one terminal -> php artisan selenium:start

and i get this:

> 11:07:40.037 INFO - Launching a standalone Selenium Server
>   Setting system property webdriver.chrome.driver to /var/www/html/dev.popt.in/releases/20190108094923/vendor/bin/linux-chrome
>   11:07:40.083 INFO - Java: Oracle Corporation 24.181-b01
>   11:07:40.083 INFO - OS: Linux 3.13.0-74-generic amd64
>   11:07:40.097 INFO - v2.53.1, with Core v2.53.1. Built from revision a36b8b1
>   11:07:40.183 INFO - Driver provider org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver registration is skipped:
>   registration capabilities Capabilities [{platform=WINDOWS, ensureCleanSession=true, browserName=internet explorer, version=}] does not match the current platform LINUX
>   11:07:40.184 INFO - Driver provider org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver registration is skipped:
>   registration capabilities Capabilities [{platform=WINDOWS, browserName=MicrosoftEdge, version=}] does not match the current platform LINUX
>   11:07:40.184 INFO - Driver class not found: com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver
>   11:07:40.184 INFO - Driver provider com.opera.core.systems.OperaDriver is not registered
>   11:07:40.185 INFO - Driver provider org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriver registration is skipped:
>   registration capabilities Capabilities [{platform=MAC, browserName=safari, version=}] does not match the current platform LINUX
>   11:07:40.186 INFO - Driver class not found: org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver
>   11:07:40.186 INFO - Driver provider org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver is not registered
>   11:07:40.266 INFO - RemoteWebDriver instances should connect to: http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub
>   11:07:40.267 INFO - Selenium Server is up and running

**And on the second terminal**
-> vendor/bin/phpunit tests/SeleniumExampleTest

**This is the result that i'm getting:**

```
    Starting ChromeDriver 2.35.528139 (47ead77cb35ad2a9a83248b292151462a66cd881) on port 4851
Only local connections are allowed.
11:01:07.358 WARN - Exception thrown
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1', time: '2016-06-30 17:37:03'
System info: host: 'ip-172-31-45-166', ip: '172.31.45.166', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.13.0-74-generic', java.version: '1.7.0_181'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:188)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession.execute(DefaultSession.java:183)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession.<init>(DefaultSession.java:119)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession.createSession(DefaultSession.java:95)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverSessions.newSession(DefaultDriverSessions.java:124)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.NewSession.handle(NewSession.java:59)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.NewSession.handle(NewSession.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.rest.ResultConfig.handle(ResultConfig.java:111)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.JsonHttpCommandHandler.handleRequest(JsonHttpCommandHandler.java:79)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DriverServlet.handleRequest(DriverServlet.java:204)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DriverServlet.doPost(DriverServlet.java:166)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DriverServlet.service(DriverServlet.java:132)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.openqa.jetty.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:428)
    at org.openqa.jetty.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.dispatch(ServletHandler.java:680)
    at org.openqa.jetty.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:571)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpContext.handle(HttpContext.java:1526)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpContext.handle(HttpContext.java:1479)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpServer.service(HttpServer.java:920)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpConnection.service(HttpConnection.java:820)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpConnection.handleNext(HttpConnection.java:986)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:837)
    at org.openqa.jetty.http.SocketListener.handleConnection(SocketListener.java:243)
    at org.openqa.jetty.util.ThreadedServer.handle(ThreadedServer.java:358)
    at org.openqa.jetty.util.ThreadPool$PoolThread.run(ThreadPool.java:537)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1', time: '2016-06-30 17:37:03'
System info: host: 'ip-172-31-45-166', ip: '172.31.45.166', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.13.0-74-generic', java.version: '1.7.0_181'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverProvider.callConstructor(DefaultDriverProvider.java:113)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverProvider.newInstance(DefaultDriverProvider.java:97)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverFactory.newInstance(DefaultDriverFactory.java:60)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$BrowserCreator.call(DefaultSession.java:222)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$BrowserCreator.call(DefaultSession.java:1)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultSession$1.run(DefaultSession.java:176)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1152)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:622)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.DefaultDriverProvider.callConstructor(DefaultDriverProvider.java:103)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.35.528139 (47ead77cb35ad2a9a83248b292151462a66cd881),platform=Linux 3.13.0-74-generic x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 60.22 seconds
Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1', time: '2016-06-30 17:37:03'
System info: host: 'ip-172-31-45-166', ip: '172.31.45.166', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.13.0-74-generic', java.version: '1.7.0_181'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:678)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:249)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:144)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:170)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:138)
    ... 14 more
11:01:07.385 WARN - Exception: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.35.528139 (47ead77cb35ad2a9a83248b292151462a66cd881),platform=Linux 3.13.0-74-generic x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 60.22 seconds
Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1', time: '2016-06-30 17:37:03'
System info: host: 'ip-172-31-45-166', ip: '172.31.45.166', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.13.0-74-generic', java.version: '1.7.0_181'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
```

Please Help!!!

Comment: Chrome Browser version?

Comment: @DebanjanB how can i check the version?

Comment: You need to get Chrome browser installed before you try to spin off a Chrome browsing session. Do you have Chrome installed?

Comment: selenium 2.53 won't work with modern Chrome.  you need to upgrade selenium